# to generate the file as per UK timestamp

Tags: java

I have stuck up in a problem I have to geneate report as per UK (England)Time 
I have run a report today 09-july-2013 as per UK time it was 5:58 AM
and in india it was 10:28 AM now the file generation should include UK time stamp 
but the file does not have that time stamp I am using this

```
String currDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm").format(new Date());
System.out.println("ABC_0101-"+currDate);
```

Please advise how to get the UK TIME in the file stamp am I missing something in 24 Hour format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the time zone of the formatter:

```
TimeZone london = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm", Locale.UK);
format.setTimeZone(london);

System.out.println("ABC_0101-" + format.format(new Date()));
```

As asides:

- That's a very odd format pattern. If it's under your control, I'd urge you to use something which is naturally sortable, e.g. `yyyy-MM-ddTHHmmss`
- I've explicitly used the UK locale to ensure that UK date symbols are used. In this case it probably doesn't matter, but in other cases it might.
- Are you sure they actually want the UK time zone rather than UTC? The UK time zone will end up with some ambiguous values due to daylight saving transitions - it may well make more sense to use UTC.
- If you're doing much date/time work, you should consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), which is a much better date/time library than `java.util.Date` etc.